# How to clean up files created by Exec resources?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to write a puppet class that will create a cirros image with OpenStacks Glance.

I have this puppet class. It downloads the image file and converts it to raw.
It then creates the glance image using the raw image format file.
I also want to remove the downloaded image file and the raw image file from
local disk.

Here is the manifest I tried:

```
class create_glance_cirros_image (
    $cirrosver           = '0.3.5',
    $cirros_download_url = 'http://download.cirros-cloud.net',
    $curl                = '/usr/bin/curl',
    $download_dir        = '/root',
    $qemu_img            = '/usr/bin/qemu-img',
    $qemu_img_args       = 'convert -f qcow2 -O raw',
    $image_name          = 'cirros',
    $is_public           = 'no',
    $container_format    = 'bare',
    $disk_format         = 'raw',
    $min_ram             = '1024',
    $min_disk            = '1',
    $properties          = { 'img_key' => img_value },
    $ensure              = 'present',
) {
    $cirros_image = "cirros-${cirrosver}-x86_64-disk.img"
    $raw_cirros_image = "cirros-${cirrosver}-x86_64-disk.raw"
    $image_url = "${cirros_download_url}/${cirrosver}/${cirros_image}"
    $target_file = "${download_dir}/${cirros_image}"
    $raw_target_file = "${download_dir}/${raw_cirros_image}"
    $curl_args = "--output ${target_file}"
    $download_command = "${curl} ${curl_args} ${image_url}"
    $convert_command = "${qemu_img} ${qemu_img_args} ${target_file} ${raw_target_file}"

    exec { $download_command:
       creates     => $target_file,
       refreshonly => true,
    }
    exec { $convert_command:
       creates     => $raw_target_file,
       refreshonly => true,
       require    => Exec[$download_command],
    }

    glance_image { $image_name:
       ensure           => $ensure,
       name             => $image_name,
       is_public        => $is_public,
       container_format => $container_format,
       disk_format      => $disk_format,
       source           => $raw_target_file,
       min_ram          => $min_ram,
       min_disk         => $min_disk,
       properties       => $properties,
       require         => Exec[$convert_command],
    }

    file { $target_file:
       ensure => 'absent',
    }
    file { $raw_target_file:
       ensure => 'absent',
    }
}
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/openstack image create --format shell cirros --private --container-format=bare --disk-format=raw --min-disk=1 --min-ram=1024 --property img_key=img_value --file=/root/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.raw' returned 1: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.raw'
Error: /Stage[main]/Create_glance_cirros_image/Glance_image[cirros]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/openstack image create --format shell cirros --private --container-format=bare --disk-format=raw --min-disk=1 --min-ram=1024 --property img_key=img_value --file=/root/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.raw' returned 1: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.raw'
```

Why didn't the require cause the exec's to execute?

Update: Based on Matt's suggestions I modified my manifest to look like this:

```
exec { $download_command:
   creates     => $target_file,
   unless => "/usr/bin/openstack image list --format=value | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep \"^${image_name}$\"",
   notify => Exec[$convert_command],
}

exec { $convert_command:
   creates     => $raw_target_file,
   refreshonly => true,
}

glance_image { $image_name:
   ensure           => present,
   name             => $image_name,
   is_public        => $is_public,
   container_format => $container_format,
   disk_format      => $disk_format,
   source           => $raw_target_file,
   min_ram          => $min_ram,
   min_disk         => $min_disk,
   properties       => $properties,
}

exec { "/bin/rm -f ${target_file}":
   subscribe   => Exec[$convert_command],
   refreshonly => true,
}

file { $raw_target_file:
   ensure  => 'absent',
   require => Glance_image[$image_name],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting your `exec` resources to `refreshonly` means that they require a refresh signal to trigger and be applied. This can be done with a `subscribe` or a `notify`. Since your second `exec` depends upon the first, you can do this as:

```
exec { $download_command:
  creates     => $target_file,
  refreshonly => true,
  notify      => Exec[$convert_command],
}
```

or:

```
exec { $convert_command:
  creates     => $raw_target_file,
  refreshonly => true,
  subscribe   => Exec[$download_command],
}
```

The first one is trickier since it does not establish a relationship with anything. If you want the file download to be idempotent, I would recommend using a `file` resource instead.

```
file { $target_file:
  source => $image_url,
}
```

This would cause both of your resources to be idempotent and apply when only when you want them to, thus achieving your goal.

You would need to modify your image file removal to be an `exec` though. Something like this would work:

```
exec { "/bin/rm -f ${target_file}":
  subscribe   => Exec[$convert_command]
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

Your raw image file removal also needs to be applied after its creation and usage:

```
file { $raw_target_file:
  ensure  => 'absent',
  require => Glance_image[$image_name],
}
```